# How to Interpret epoch time with concatenated timezone in python

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a timestamp string in epoch format with a concatenated timezone:

```
'1602483300000+0200'
```

How can I interpret this as datetime without string parsing in advance?
Thanks!

Comment: Without string parsing means that `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1347517370))` you want to do this?

Comment: By "without parsing" I meant that I didn't need to remove the '+0200' timezone part at the end.

Comment: I don’t think you can. This format doesn’t seem to make much sense, as the unix epoch is timezone-independent. You also don’t need to do any real "parsing", you can just split off the last 5 characters.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what I could imagine here is that UNIX time is not UNIX time but off by the local time zone's UTC offset (you can't always prevent people from being clever...). Python datetime's internal handling of time as local time by default and not UTC also isn't beneficial IMHO. Here, it *might* be necessary to subtract the '+0200' offset.

Answer (score 2):

- suffix like '+0200' is an offset from UTC (usually), not a time zone
- since the input is `str` and you want `datetime`, you'll need to parse it *somehow*
- "epoch time" *should* refer to UTC, see [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so adding a UTC offset info doesn't make much sense unless the seconds-since-the-epoch part does **not** refer to UTC.

0. the parsing...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import re

timestring = '1602483300000+0200'
# split on + or - in case there are different offsets
parts = re.split('\+|\-', timestring)
s, off = float(parts[0])/1000, timedelta(hours=int(parts[1][:2]),
                                         minutes=int(parts[1][2:])).total_seconds()
```

1. assuming first part is seconds since the epoch / UNIX time:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(s, timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 12, 6, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

2. assuming first part of string is **not** actually UNIX time (the offset has a meaning):

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(s-off, timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 12, 4, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```